# Load column from Database into list

Tags: django

How do you load a database column into a list with Django? I have a 'name' column of various names in my database and I want to be able to load all those names (ordered by id) into a list. So that I can iterate over that list and print the names, like this:

```
for name in name_list:
      print name
```

I've googled this pretty thoroughly and I can't find anything. This should be so simple, its just the equivalent of SQL's "SELECT column FROM table"

```
class chat_messages(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
```

Comment: First, indent your code sample properly.  Second, provide the actual class definition for this "'name' column of various names" or whatever it is you're talking about.  Third, please read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/queries/#making-queries and include **specific** questions related to that documentation for Django queries.

Comment: What part of `chat_messages.objects.all()` was confusing?  Please be specific about your question.

Comment: Frist and Second.. See above. 
Thirdly, I've read that guide, and the 2.0 version and they say nothing about simply reading a column from a database, into a list.

Comment: chat_messages.objects.all() returns EVERYTHING. Not a specific column. I wan't to only retrieve a column. That is specific.

Comment: It's a collection of objects, each object has *all* the columns in your original table.    You rarely want to get a list of column values in Django.  You can read about the `values()` function, but this isn't really very useful.  Is that what you're asking about?

Comment: list = chat_messages.objects.all().values('name') works, but then when I iterate the list everything is in a wacky format like this: {'name': u'billy'}

Comment: You should probably reference the documentation.  Self-help is worth so much more than community help.  And Django's documentation is **fantastic**.   Check it out:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/

Comment: `{'name': u'billy'}` is not a "wacky" format.   A quick read of a Python tutorial might help you out more than asking this kind of question.

Comment: Also, please **update** the question to be specific, please don't just add a lot of comments.  They're hard to read and they make it hard for people with a similar problem to learn from your question.  Also, what you think of as **specific** may not be enough information for others.  It's okay to provide **extra** information.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Check out [the docs for `values_list()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list).  Django does a great job of creating the query specific to your request.

```
chat_messages.objects.all().values_list('name')
```

Will generate a query similar to:

```
SELECT `projectname_chat_messages`.`name` FROM `projectname_chat_messages`
```

Comment: thaaaankk you. I knew there had to be a simple command to handle this. For some reason they don't mention that in the Models Chapter of the Django book.

Comment: x = chat_messages.objects.all().values_list('name', flat=True).order_by('id') is exactly what I was looking for. Loads the 'name' column, in order of 'id' and it is just a pure (aka flat) list.

Comment: To be honest, the DjangoProject.com site has better information than the DjangoBook.  It is a fantastic resource in itself.

Comment: I am trying on my side but somewhere I am getting an Attribute error on the particular column, the reason it shows that The Serializer field might be name incorrectly and not matched but it's working in case of POST, UPDATE, DELETE but when i am trying to fetch with using values_list its not working even when i am fetching complete data using all() still it's working, please help me out